# Programmatically login to Facebook using username/password

Tags: facebook, authentication, rest, curl

Ok, I've been looking for over an hour on this subject and can only find OAuth solutions, which I do not need or want.

I need to authenticate as myself to Facebook from a location other than Facebook. I need my website (admin area) to authenticate to Facebook for me and post in my behalf, on my wall, or my friends wall. This is an administration tool, and I don't want to login into Facebook every time I post to my website. I need this admin extension to login for me, and add an automated post with a title and image: "New post on example.com".

It feels like I've been looking everywhere and can only find solutions with creating a FB application, granting it certain rights, using oauth, etc-overly-complicated-process, which is (dare-i-say) rather stupid since I don't want to authenticate other people, like visitors. I simply want to emulate my(self|browser), as if I'm the one navigating through their pages and not an automated tool. Of course I could probably go the cURL way and emulate a real user-agent but I'm not about to start scraping FB pages.

Is there a programmatic way of authenticating to FB using a simple user/pass (not even stored on the server) and get the same rights I normally get when authenticating through a browser? And of course, obtain needed data in a json or other machine parse-able encapsulation ? I would assume I need to send a cookie or some form of token on susequent requests, but that's not a problem, I just need a way of authenticating with a simple user/pass and bypass that whole app registration ache.

I'd need something similar to twitter and google+ maybe (?) I did find a simple class for twitter but nothing on google+ (same problem, twitter is pushing hard for their way of creating an app and using oauth, but they do maintain a way of authenticating as yourself through simple REST requests).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to do what you're describing, other than a painful and non-supported method of emulating a user agent.  It's also not a good practice to do what you're describing, as Facebook (and other websites for that matter) should not allow 3rd parties to collect usernames/passwords, even if it's only in transit.  I understand that in your scenario, you will be the only user, but Facebook has to design their API for the masses.

Why not set up a Facebook App and use oauth?  You'll only need to authorize your App once, get an offline access token, and then use that access token from then on.  I think this will be easier than the approach you're looking for because you won't need to authenticate with Facebook every time.  You just need the access token.

Note that the offline access token will expire if you change your Facebook password or you de-authorize your app.

Comment: :) i just find no point in creating an app for myself, and me being the only user. I believed apps are for providing new features to "other people" who would want to install your app and thus allow you access to their data on different levels.

Plus, this is an admin area that is part of a bigger application which is installed on the client's location. I would rather tell the client that he can post to FB from the admin area and not ask him to create an app and authorize himself as a user :)

Comment: There are certainly benefits to making a separate app, even if you're the only person posting from it.  You've said you want the app to post stuff to your wall.  People who have friended you might not want to be constantly bombarded with that spam.  So, facebook gives them the option of blocking everything you say, or blocking everything your app says.  I'm sure you'd prefer the latter.

Comment: True, but the FB accounts used would be corporate/business accounts or pages, so the people following those pages would be interested exactly in the information posted through the online app. In other words, nobody would authenticate to FB as that user anyway, if they had a way to do it directly from the admin area.

Comment: Hi @George, I don't think all of your clients will need to create an App.  You can create one App that all of your clients use.  They'll have to authorize your App once, of course, but using oauth in this way avoids exactly what Facebook doesn't want you to do, which is to store a user's Facebook credentials outside of Facebook.

Comment: That's a very good point, @JohnnyO. So using a single application, the client would have to authorize that app to post on his/her behalf and he would be asked to authenticate twice (once for the admin tool, and once for FB) in order to post from the admin tool, right ? Can I avoid the second auth, to FB ? The thing is, more than one people may use the admin panel, and some should be able to post to FB using the company's account. This means that they all need to know a second user/pass for their company's FB account ... again things get more complex than I feel they should be.

Comment: In that scenario, what you can do is have one person from your client authorize your App on Facebook with the account they want to use to publish stuff to Facebook.  When that account authorizes your App, you will receive an offline access token for that account.  Store that access token somewhere, and use it for all Facebook API calls for that client.  Be careful that you don't violate Facebook's T&C though.  Facebook user accounts/profiles need to be associated with a single user and not an organization.

Comment: ok, thanks for a very good lead. 
do offline access tokens expire ? I believe when the clients authorizes the app, he would check a checkbox with offline-access. How does the token arrive to me ?

Comment: nevermind, I got the details: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Thanks again!

Comment: @George, I don't think that link does a good job of explaining when offline access tokens expire.  Here is a Facebook blog post that explains it better: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/.  In summary, offline access tokens expire if a user changes his/her password or de-authorizes your app.