# Login into facebook by sending User Name and Password from Data Base in Android

Tags: android, facebook

I want to login in face book account from my android app.The User Name & Password are already stored in my Database and when i press the button in the app, at that time using that user name & password it is automatically login to face book account and fetch some detail and display.

Comment: Storing username and password in your database is not the best approach, security wise! Use the [access tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens) that facebook provides in order to access facebook content!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically login to Facebook using username/password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614356/programmatically-login-to-facebook-using-username-password)